# EJB JPA transactions

Tags: jpa, transactions, ejb

I am using JSF 2.1, EJB 3.1, JPA 2.0, Glassfish 3.1.1 and NetBeans 7.0.1.

For each entity class I created a separate Facade class, for example, UserFacade and AddressFacade using NetBeans tools. These two entities are not related to each other and are completely independent of each of other. However, I need to put them into database during one transaction and if one fails to be inserted then another one should also be rollbacked. How can I do that? As far as I know EJB container manages transactions itself and doesn't allow to manually control the transaction boundaries.

Comment: I found answer to my question. If someone is interested then it is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html).

Comment: Is there a difference between your link and my answer? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction will be rollback everything as long as you "touch" both of your entities in the same persist, update or remove, however, you say that they are not related to each other in anyway and so Im guessing that you have to perform 2 persists and that will not be in the same transaction scope.

**Option 1**

You could do something easy and ugly for this, there is @PrePersist and @PreUpdate in JPA that you can make sure that everything is with the previous persist. This will make a bad codebase and force unwanted dependencies.

**Option 2**

You could simply have a relation between User and Address, which is only natural.

**Option 3**

The third option is to use [Bean Managed Transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html)

Comment: with option 2, are you implying that there be a relationship between the two entities AND that the cascade feature be turned on?

Comment: yes that was my thought. It might require a bit of rework but it's kinda a natural to have a address for a user.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Even if one wasn't going to use the cascade feature. Its hard to think of a use case where an address and a user shouldn't have an explicit relationship.

Answer (score 2):

In the very basic case, every public method of an EJB is executed in one transaction that rolled back when an exception is thrown inside the method.

So if you create both entities in the same method, the creations will be wrapped in one transaction.

Comment: In my case I've got two calls to EJB public methods. For instance, userFacade.create(user) and addressFacade(address) inside of one method. However, userFacade and addressFacade are two different instances of two different Facade classes and the two entities are put in 2 different transactions which I checked myself. When one entity failed to be put into database, the second one was successfully inserted into database.

Comment: You should restructure your code so that actions belonging together are executed in the same business method.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to control transactions yourself. This feature is called **Bean-Managed Transactions** (BMT). You can read more about them [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction4.html).

Also you'll need to understand `TransactionManagement` thing. Oracle describes it in this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/servtran001.htm).

**Example:**

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyEJB implements MyEJBLocal {

  @Resource
  private EJBContext context;

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public void doMyAction() {
    UserTransaction transaction = context.getUserTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    ... create myEntity ...

    em.persist(myEntity);
    transaction.commit();
  }

}
```

Comment: This tutorial is for J2EE and quite outdated regarding he is using EJB 3.1

Comment: BMT is a very old concept, so there were no reasons to downvote ;) The link is related to J2EE, but it contains some code samples, while a new tutorial does not.